# Hitting Enemy (Flash AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

My Hero and Enemy movieclips are nested inside a map movieclip.

The Hero adds another moveclip like this:

```
parent.addChild(_Punch);
_Punch.x = this.x;
_Punch.y = this.y;
```

The Map Movieclip that contains both the Hero and the Enemy is where the _punch is being added.
The Enemy has the instance name of "Sheep"
How then, do I access the punch? Do I do this inside the punches Class File?
My main question is that I do not know how to access the punch.

Comment: more code is required

Comment: It's generally bad form to have one display object create a sibling - separation of concerns and all.  Ideally parents should create and manage their children.

Comment: Please explain the context more.  Where is the code you 've shown in relation to everything else?  Where do you want to access `_Punch`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you write your logic and how you place your objects.

You can always access Movieclips with their instance names. 
If a MovieClip is inside the parent movieclip then you will write as follows:

MovieClip(parent).movieclip_instance_name.x = ..

To access the child of the same MC, you will do as follows:

MovieClip(parent).movieclip_instance_name.child.x ...

Also, to check collision you would use HitTestObject or HitTest ideally inside the ENTER_FRAME event.

Again all depends upon your scenario and your own logic of doing the same.

Cheers